# building a quiz app local variable 'answer_selection' referenced before assignment

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to build an app which manages electronic quizzes,

The model works perfectly fine when I try to add a question but the problem is when I try to post the user answers it won't work.

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(CourseType, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    question = models.TextField(max_length=200,default="")
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

**forms.py**

```
MULTIPLE_CHOICE= [
    ('A', 'A'),
    ('B', 'B'),
    ('C', 'C'),
    ('D', 'D'),]
class TestForm(forms.Form):
  right_answer= forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=MULTIPLE_CHOICE))

views.py
def test_view(request, question_id):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect('cal:signin')
    form = TestForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            right_answer = form.cleaned_data['right_answer']
            quiz = form.save(commit=False)
            answer_selection = Question.objects.get(id=question_id.answer)
            scores = 0
            for find_right_answer in answer_selection:
                if find_right_answer == option1 or find_right_answer == option2 or find_right_answer == option3 or find_right_answer == option4:
                    find_right_answer = Question.objects.filter(id=question_id)
                    scores += 1
                else:
                    scores -= 1
            quiz.save()
            return redirect('cal:quiz-page')
    context = {'form':form,'answer_selection':answer_selection}
    return render(request, 'cal/quiz_page.html', context)
```

**quiz_page.html**

```
{% extends "cal/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Quiz !t{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<br>
<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header">choose!</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">
        <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for option in answer_selection %}
          <input type="radio" id="student_{{ option.id }}" name="option" value="{{ option.id }}">
          <label for="optionent_{{ stud.id }}">{{ option.option1 }}</label>
          <input type="radio" id="student_{{ option.id }}" name="option" value="{{ option.id }}">
          <label for="optionent_{{ stud.id }}">{{ option.option2 }}</label>
          <input type="radio" id="student_{{ option.id }}" name="option" value="{{ option.id }}">
          <label for="optionent_{{ stud.id }}">{{ option.option3 }}</label>
          <input type="radio" id="student_{{ option.id }}" name="option" value="{{ option.id }}">
          <label for="optionent_{{ stud.id }}">{{ option.option4 }}</label>
        {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py**

```
  url(r'^quiz/list/(?P<question_id>\d+)/$',views.test_view, name='quiz-page'),
```

The expected result is to show a page with the question and 4 radio buttons. When the user selects the right answer it should increase their scores, and when they select the wrong answer it'll decrease his scores.

Comment: If `if form.is_valid():` is not assigned, your `answer_selection` is *not* assigned, but you still use it in your `{'answer_selection': answer_selection}`.

Comment: so how to assign it? I don't think I got what you mean!